# Checking if a point is singular by looking at the algebraic definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to calculate if a point is singular or not. What I want to use is that a point is nonsingular if $\dim_k( m_p/m^2_p)=1$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of an algebraic curve at a point $p$.

My given variety is $V(x^2-y^3,y^2-z^3)$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$ and $p=(0,0,0)$.

By previous work in the proof of theorem 2 in chapter 3 (Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*) we know that

$$\dim m_p/m_p^2= \dim \mathcal O/ m_p^2- \dim \mathcal O/ m_p.$$

I am good with that my problem is that we showed that $ \mathcal O/ m_p= \mathcal O (\mathbb{C}^2)/(F,I^n) \mathcal O(\mathbb{C}^2)$. My problem here is that first we have 3 variables not 2 and then F in the book is the curve defining the variety but here I have two such polynomials. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate ring of your variety is $R=\mathbb C[x,y,z]/\langle x^2-y^3, y^2-z^3\rangle$. Denoting the images of $x,y,z $ in the quotient as $\tilde x,\tilde y,\tilde z$, we now localize $R$ at $I_p=\langle \tilde x,\tilde y,\tilde z\rangle$ in $R$, the ideal of $p=(0,0,0)$ in this ring. Since localization commutes with quotients, we first localize $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ at $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ and then take the quotient. Now, $m_p/m_p^2=\langle\tilde x,\tilde y,\tilde z \rangle/\langle\tilde x^2,\tilde y^2,\tilde z^2,\tilde x\tilde y,\tilde y \tilde z,\tilde x\tilde z\rangle$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space. Suppose $$p\tilde x+q\tilde y+r\tilde z\in \langle\tilde x^2,\tilde y^2,\tilde z^2,\tilde x\tilde y,\tilde y \tilde z,\tilde x\tilde z\rangle$$ for some $p,q,r\in \mathbb C$. This is the same as $$px+qy+rz\in \langle x^2, y^2,z^2,x y,y z, x z\rangle +\langle x^2-y^3, y^2-z^3 \rangle=\langle x^2, y^2,z^2,x y,y z, x z\rangle.$$ So $p,q,r$ are zero because the ideal $\langle x^2, y^2,z^2,x y,y z, x z\rangle$ contains no linear polynomials.

If my calculations are right, $m_p/m_p^2\cong \mathbb C^3$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following easy observation:

Let $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}(A/I) \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ with $I \subset \mathfrak p^2$ (This is satisfied in our case!). Then

$$(\mathfrak p/I)/(\mathfrak p/I)^2 = (\mathfrak p/I)/(\mathfrak p^2+I/I) = (\mathfrak p/I)/(\mathfrak p^2/I) \cong \mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^2,$$

i.e. the dimension of the tangent space does not change when passing to the closed subvariety. Hence, in our case, the dimension will be indeed $3$, since the tangent space of the polynomial ring in three variables is $3$-dimensional in any closed point.